# How do I enable a button after a delay using AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am using the `ng-disabled` directive to control when a button on my page can be clicked. Is it possible to control this via a timer? I would like the button to be disbaled until 5 seconds have elapsed. My HTML is currently:

```
<div ng-controller="ResetController">
    <button ng-click="reset()">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Comment: please post your code

Comment: What is ngEnabled, is it custom directive of you mean ngDisabled? `<button ng-disabled="disabled"></button>` and `$timeout(function() { $scope.disabled = false }, 5000)`.

Comment: yes - I should be using ngDisabled. Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use `$timeout`:

```
$timeout(function() {
   $scope.buttonEnabled = true;
}, 5000);
```

And in your html:

```
<button ng-click="reset()" ng-disabled="!buttonEnabled">Reset</button>
```

Also don't forget to inject `$timeout` into your controller. Like any other angular Service (`$http` for example).

Answer (score 7):

`ng-enabled` isn't in core, but `ng-disabled` evaluates based on either true or false so simply use a timeout to assign true to a variable after a desired amount of time to enable accordingly.

html:

```
<button ng-disabled="isDisabled">click me after 3 seconds</button>
```

controller:

```
function($scope, $timeout) {
  $scope.isDisabled= true;
  $timeout(function(){
    $scope.isDisabled= false;
  }, 3000)
}
```

Comment: There is no `ng-enabled`, or am I missing something? Also it should be 5 seconds, not 3.

Comment: I've not done angular for a while in favour of react, just realised, and was mid edit as you commented. :)

Answer (score 3):

You need to set a variable in your controller, then set ng-disabled using that variable.

For example, assuming a controller ExampleController registered with controller-as "example":

```
(function() {
    'use strict';
    angular.module('app').controller('ExampleController',ExampleController);
    ExampleController.$inject = ['$timeout'];

    function ExampleController($timeout) {
        var vm = this;
        vm.buttonDisabled = true;
        $timeout(function() { 
            vm.buttonDisabled = false;
        }, 5000);
    }
})();
```

Then in your template:

```
<input type="button" ng-disabled="example.buttonDisabled"/>
```

Comment: I think it might be worth the correct vote because of all of the best practices in this answer, not something that is strictly necessary, but beneficial to someone new and starting out.

Comment: Thanks @AdamCooper86 - one of the problems I had starting out with Angular was the number of different ways there are to do things, the controller-as syntax and proper isolation of different elements was something that many examples missed but really helps to keep clean, testable, & bug-free code.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use timeout as per the previous answer ...

```
$scope.buttonDisabled = true;

$timeout(function() {
   $scope.buttonDisabled = false;
}, 5000);
```

don't forget to inject $timeout into your controller / service.

then in your HTML do ...

```
<div ng-controller="ResetController">
    <button ng-click="reset()" ng-disabled="buttonDisabled">Reset</button>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
var interval= setInterval(timePassed, 1000);
function timePassed() {
   $scope.buttonEnabled = true;
}
```

and:

```
<input type="button" ng-enabled="buttonEnabled"/>
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. You'd need to use `$interval` or `$timeout` or manually digest